# JSON Deserialization of interface types in .NET7

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, .net-7.0

I am working on an ASP .NET Core App to build a Blazor hosted web app.
In response to a GET request to an endpoint, the Server builds a list of objects and returns them to client as

```
public class SensorsPagerResult
{
    public IEnumerable<ISensor> Sensors { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

The Client gets the response and tries to deserialize it as :

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = await _client.GetAsync($"api/sensors?skip={skip}&take={take}&orderby={orderBy}");
if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await resp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SensorsPagerResult>(jsOptions);
```

and there ReadFromJSonAsync throws an exception stating that "deserialization of interface types is not supported"
I understand that .NET 7 added [lots of enhancements to this particular scenario](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/), but I am just unable to leverage it for my case. I tried to use the JSonDerivedType decorator, but don't really understand how to use it for generic types.

I have below data models with what I would need serialization support:

```
public interface IMeasurement
{
    DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public interface IMeasurement<T> : IMeasurement where T : class
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
public class THSData
{
    public double Temp { get; set; }
    public double Hum { get; set; }
    public int RSSI { get; set; }
    public int Battery { get; set; }
}

public class THSMeasurement : IMeasurement<THSData>
{
    public THSData Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public interface ISensor
{
    SensorType Type { get; init; }
    string ID { get; init; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface ISensor<U, T> : ISensor where U : IMeasurement<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<U> GetMeasurements { get; }
    void AddMeasurement(U measurement);
    void AddMeasurements(IEnumerable<U> measurements);
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ISensor), typeDiscriminator:"THSSensor")]
public class THSensor : ISensor<THSMeasurement, THSData>
{
    private List<THSMeasurement> _measurements = new List<THSMeasurement>();
    public string ID { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public SensorType Type { get; init; }
    IEnumerable<THSMeasurement> ISensor<THSMeasurement, THSData>.GetMeasurements => _measurements;

    public THSensor(string ID, string Description)  {... }

    public void AddMeasurement(THSMeasurement measurement) {...}

    public void AddMeasurements(IEnumerable<THSMeasurement> measurements) {...}
}
```

So any idea please how to perform Json deserialization of the SensorsPagerResult class which contains a property of type `IEnumerable<ISensor>`?